# Input type file - how to access files property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've started to rewrite some of my Javascript code in Typescript to learn how Typescript works. However I'm at a point where the Type annotations make some trouble.

I try to get a file from an input field, in Javascript I do

```
var file = document.getElementById('upload_files').files[0];
```

what I now try to write in typescript but I can't figure out, how I've to cast to access the `.files` property in Typescript.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out..

I had to cast the element to a `HTMLInputElement` thats where the `files` property is included.

```
var fileElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('upload_files');
var file = fileElement.files[0];
```

Comment: Even better, you should use `document.getElementById('upload_files') as HTMLInputElement`, as this is the preferred syntax for type _assertions_ (not type _casting_).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176930/23118) for a HTMLInputEvent type.