# Mock FileList for Unit Test Angular 5 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Mock [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

I am trying to write a unit test (Angular5) that requires a FileList. I have looked everywhere for any hint at a solution. *I am wondering if this is even possible because of the security nature of FileList and my quest has been doomed from the start.*

If this is possible **any** pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know jasmine, but the only spec wise way to **create a writable** FileList from scratch is through the `DataTransfer` constructor (currently only available in Blink) . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409 for a demo.

Comment: We don't have debates here.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/amabes/88324d68690e0e7b8e313cd0cafaa219

Comment: @Kaiido, seems like this question is not a duplicate to the one you've marked. Could you please remove the mark or clarify the reason of marking as duplicate?

Comment: @AlanMabry you may want to post as an answer.

Answer (score 17):

**Option 1: Using DataTransfer Constructor**

```
describe('Component', () => {
  const getFileList = () => {
    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    dt.items.add(new File([], 'file.csv'));
    return dt.files;
  };

  it('should mock fileList', () => {
    component.fileList = getFileList();
  });
});
```

**Option 2: Mocking Filelist with Blob**

```
describe('Component', () => {
  const getFileList = () => {
    const blob = new Blob([""], { type: "text/html" });
    blob["lastModifiedDate"] = "";
    blob["name"] = "filename";
    const file = <File>blob;
    const fileList: FileList = {
      0: file,
      1: file,
      length: 2,
      item: (index: number) => file
    };
    return fileList;
  };

  it('should mock fileList', () => {
    component.fileList = getFileList();
  });
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: And if you need a `HTMLInputEvent` type see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176930/23118).