# What is the type for an event in Vue TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

What is the correct type for 'e' as in uploadImage function parameter?

```
public uploadImage(e /* :type of e */){
 const image = e.target.files[0];
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(image);
 reader.onload = e =>{
    this.previewImage = e.target.result;
    console.log(this.previewImage);
 };
}
```

In template I have this

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" @change=uploadImage>
```

Answer (score 28):

The type is just `Event`. Relevant information is on `e.target` property.

Answer (score 11):

Obviously I'm late to the party, but I was rewriting some legacy components. In the end I ran into Typescript errors - the template event didn't like me destructuring directly because the `target` was `EventTarget`, not `HTMLInputElement` or whatever the given element I needed.

So instead of directly destructuring the arguments I just set it afterwards as a variable, using the `as` keyword.

Example:

```js
foo(event: Event) {
  const el = event.target as HTMLInputElement
  // do stuff
}
```

I wish I knew some handy trick to destructure it from the arguments directly with the correct type, but alas I haven't been that fortunate.

Answer (score 10):

You can use your self annotation for this type.

```
interface InputFileEvent extends Event {
    target: HTMLInputElement;
}

public uploadImage(e: InputFileEvent) {
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    reader.onload = e =>{
        this.previewImage = e.target.result;
        console.log(this.previewImage);
   };
}
```

Comment: TS is still complaining about incompatible vue @events

Answer (score 2):

If you give the type as `Event`, then you will be unable to do `e.target.files[0];` as TS will complain that `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'target' error in typescript`. The simplest solution is to give it type as `any` referring shusson's solution here: [Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' error in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176560/property-files-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-typescript/43176721#43176721) but even this didn't work for me so I ended up just not using TS for that particular Vue component

Comment: If the type `any` does not even work, you probably tried to make something work that can't work, may it be with or without types. Using `any` is wrong in the first place because by that you disable the advantage of Typescript. If you plan to do that, the better solution is (honestly) to uninstall Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

There are different type of events and types. For example you can use **DragEvent** type for drag action : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent.
There is also **InputEvent** for inputs. : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent.
The Event is more generic.
[image]