# Type of event during form submit in vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am getting `Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)` from the code below -

```
const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = event.target.elements.email?.value;
    const password = event.target.elements.password?.value;

    console.log(email, password);
};
```

Searched around but didn't found any answer which can solve it, any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: The type is being inferred here because you did not declare it, therefore it defaults to `any`. You must declare the type, such as `event: Event`. In a TypeScript environment -- by default -- you must strongly declare function arguments typings.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks!

Comment: You can also allow `implicit any`.  This is useful when you are migrating legacy code into your application.

Answer (score -1):

I tried casting the `event.target as HTMLInputElement` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154245/14536215), but I still got complaints for missing parameters. I ended up doing this in the end

```
async function newPlayer(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  console.log(formData.get("name"))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a `typescript` error.  You can `explicitly` give it an `any` type.  Or give it an actual type.  Or change your `typescript` settings to allow `implicit any`.

```
const handleFormSubmit = (event:any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = event.target.elements.email?.value;
    const password = event.target.elements.password?.value;

    console.log(email, password);
};
```

Comment: How would you go about giving it an actual type?

Comment: Instead of `event:any`, you would replace `any` with the type.  For example, `event: Event`

Comment: Sure, but that just leads to other typescript errors, if you want to access `event.target.elements.email?.value`: `'event.target' is possibly 'null'.` and `Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Comment: Yea those would be other typescript issues. But if you get those errors, it means you have solved the issues you posted

Comment: You probably got downvotes because your issue has plenty of related answers already.  Its a common issue.  I have found it sometimes makes sense to turn off ALL the typescript strict checks, then turn them on one at a time.