# What's the correct way to type an onChange handler for input type files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Almost like [Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' error in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176560/property-files-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-typescript)

What's the correct way to type an onChange handler for input type files?

```
<input
        id="myInput"
        type="file"
        ref={inputEl}
        onChange={onChangeFile}
      />

///
const onChangeFile = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
    const arr = files.filter((file: any) => imageTypesRegExp.test(file.type));
  };
```

Which throws errors like:

```
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

for the `event.target.files` and

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

for the `file.type`

Comment: I'm not familiar with React.js, so pardon this question, but is `onChange` being wired-up by React.js specifically using `addEventListener`, or is it using the old-school HTML3-era `onchange=""`-style event attributes?

Comment: React have it's own event system, I'm not sure about the internals. https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm unfamiliar with React/ReactJS, so I'm using only [the DOM `Event` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

- You need to cast `event.target` (or `event.currentTarget`) to `HTMLInputElement`.
- This is because the `Event` interface is not generic (so [the type of `target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) or [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) cannot be specified).

Like so:

```
const onChangeFile = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement; // <-- here
    const files = Array.from(input.files);
    const arr   = files.filter((file: any) => imageTypesRegExp.test(file.type));
};
```

---

As an aside, you don't need this event-handler at all if you want to filter files by MIME type or file-extension, [instead use the `<input accept="" />` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Unique_file_type_specifiers), like so:

- Only JPEG and PNG images:

  ```
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" />
  ```
- Any image:

  ```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
  ```
- Only video:

  ```
  <input type="file" accept="video/*" />
  ```