# Typescript onChange Input event.nativeEvent.target.file

Tags: typescript

I want to make my code TypeSafe but I get the error Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

`<Input onChange={(e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => onChangeImage(e.nativeEvent?.target?.files[0])}`

Comment: perhaps it's case sensitive, shouldn't it be `input` and `onchange` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' error in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176560/property-files-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

See the related Typescript issue here for solutions / workarounds:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31816

Also possible duplicate here:
[Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' error in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176560/property-files-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-typescript/44932086#44932086)